# XPath to produce a result node-set containing the same node more than once?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What I tried to say in the title is:

Given a bit of XML in which I know a particular element appears only once, is it possible using a *single* XPath query to select a node-set that contains that element twice?

I understand there's a "union" operator (|) but that's basically a logical-OR, right?  In SQL terms I'm looking then for the equivalent of a "union all".

E.g.   Given the XML fragment...

```
<toplevel>
  <ElementIWant>
    <SomeSubElement1>specific data</SomeSubElement1>
    <SomeSubElement2>specific data 2</SomeSubElement2>
  </ElementIWant>
</toplevel>
```

...is there a query that will get me a result set equivalent to...

```
<ElementIWant>
  ...identical content...
</ElementIWant>
<ElementIWant>
  ...identical content...
</ElementIWant>
```

I haven't found anything that makes me think it can be done - but that's why I'm asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath gives you node-**sets**, so by definition nodes appear only once. 
Now, you can have named template and call it twice with same XPath.

```
<xsl:template match="/ElementIWant"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="repeat"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="repeat"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="repeat"> 
  <xsl:copy select=".">
    <xsl:text>... same content ...</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: well, that's the only way to do it ;-)

Comment: Cheers (both).  Next time I'll try to remember that, just sometimes, the terminology is there to help us!

Answer (score 3):

*As pointed in the other answers, XPath cannot modify an XML document and produce new nodes*.

Any node can participate in a node-set only once, due to the definition of `"set"`.

**However, XPath 2.0 gives us the new [sequence type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#sequences),** which allows items to be repeated.

In order to have an element appearing twice in a sequence, one would just use [**the sequence concatenation operator `","`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concatenate) as in the below expression:

**`/*/ElementYouWant, /*/ElementYouWant`**

Put this into an XSLT2.0 stylesheet as simple as this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <t>
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "/*/ElementYouWant, /*/ElementYouWant"/>
   </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And apply this transformation on this XML document:

```
<toplevel>
    <ElementYouWant>
        <SomeSubElement1>specific data</SomeSubElement1>
        <SomeSubElement2>specific data 2</SomeSubElement2>
    </ElementYouWant>
</toplevel>
```

to produce the wanted result:

```
<t>
   <ElementYouWant>
            <SomeSubElement1>specific data</SomeSubElement1>
            <SomeSubElement2>specific data 2</SomeSubElement2>
      </ElementYouWant>
   <ElementYouWant>
            <SomeSubElement1>specific data</SomeSubElement1>
            <SomeSubElement2>specific data 2</SomeSubElement2>
      </ElementYouWant>
</t>
```

Do note, that if one uses the [**`<xsl:sequence>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sequence) instruction, no new copy of the `<ElementYouWant>` element is created -- therefore in XSLT 2.0 it is recommended to use `<xsl:sequence>` and to avoid using [**`<xsl:copy-of>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-copy-of) which creates (unnecessary) copies of nodes.

Comment: Dam,I am going to have to learn xpath all over again. :) thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a language to query the data within an XML document while the SQL `UNION ALL` syntax combines resultsets from two different queries.

XPath by itself cannot be used to present the existing data in a format that does not match the existing format. However, you could use XSLT to perform this transformation:

```
<x:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <x:output method="xml"/>

  <x:template match="/">
    <topMostLevel>
      <x:apply-templates />
    </topMostLevel>
  </x:template>

  <x:template match="toplevel">
    <x:copy-of select="."/>
    <x:copy-of select="."/>
  </x:template>
</x:stylesheet>
```